# How to validate only one textbox at a time on click of events

Tags: java, events, event-handling, zk

I created a customized text box as below for using it as url box

```
private class URLBox extends Textbox {
        // String value =null;
        URLBox(String infoValue) {
            if (!Utility.isBlank(infoValue)) {
                setValue(infoValue);

            } else {
                setValue("Enter URL");

            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void initialize() {
            addEventListener("onClick", new EventListener() {

                public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {

                    Textbox tb = (Textbox) event.getTarget();
                    if (tb.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Enter URL")) {
                        tb.setValue("");
                    }

                }
            });



            addEventListener("onBlur", new EventListener() {

                public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {

                    final URLBox tb = (URLBox) event.getTarget();
                    if (Utility.isBlank(tb.getValue())) {
                        tb.setValue("Enter URL");
                    } else if (!PeopleInfoViewModel.IsMatch(tb.getValue())) {
                         Messagebox.show("Please Enter a valid URL");

                    }

                }

            });

        }

    }
```

similar i have done for number box.
My problem is when i enter a invalid url in url box and clicks on numberbox it starts validating number box too. and i want that until it fulfills the requirement of url box it should not start validating number box
How can i achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you are adding the URLBox to the parent? I am afraid you are adding numberbox for both text box 'URL' and 'Number Box' while adding to the parent.

Comment: No am adding both separately.

Comment: Can you paste the code for the number box and the place where you add the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Ha, you had me stumped for a good while there. And on Christmas Eve too, shame on you ;)

I was able to reproduce your problem and it's simply an artifact of using `Messagebox.show`. When an `onBlur` event detects a validation problem, you call `Messagebox.show` which displays the message box. The message box has an 'Ok' button on it, which takes *focus* in the DOM. By giving focus to the button, the `NumberBox` looses focus and the `onBlur` event is fired, even if you had just selected it.

I hope that makes sense. This 'double validation' problem will go away if you remove the `Messagebox` which, from a UX perspective, you really should.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is instead of giving the initialize() method, move the event listener part to class level like this

```
final class OnClickListener implements EventListener {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
            Textbox tb = (Textbox) event.getTarget();
                    if (tb.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Enter URL")) {
                        tb.setValue("");
                    }
        }
    }

final class OnBlurListener implements EventListener {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
           final URLBox tb = (URLBox) event.getTarget();
                    if (Utility.isBlank(tb.getValue())) {
                        tb.setValue("Enter URL");
                    } else if (!PeopleInfoViewModel.IsMatch(tb.getValue())) {
                         Messagebox.show("Please Enter a valid URL");

                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do the same for number box too.

Comment: the urlBoxes and numberBoxes are being generated dynamically. a page can contain any number of urlboxes and number boxes. so the thing is if there is a onlick event on one number box it is onblur event for another numberbox. so for both the numberboxes vaidation is working together. and it should not be the case.